# SpringBoot, JPA, JPARepository findAll() returns empty Value

Tags: database, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

I have decided to use Springboot as my Backendframework. However I am facing some issues using JPARepositories.

If I use the findAll-method within a HTTP Call everything works fine!

BUT I also want to use the JPARepository to access my DB without calling a controller or HTTP Request .. here is my code ( a bit messy as I am literally trying since 2 days to solve this issue)

Here is my code:

Application Class:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories
@SpringBootApplication
public class WebappBackendApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(WebappBackendApplication.class, args);
```

JPA Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="t_mitglieder")
public class TMitglieder {
private Long id;
private String mitgliedsnr;
private String mitgliedsart;
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface MemberRepository extends JpaRepository<TMitglieder, Long>{
}
```

A java class to call my repository (this class is instantly called after the main Application (for Test issues as I do not want to make a HTTP Request):

```
public class CommandLineAppStartupRunner implements CommandLineRunner {
@Autowired
private FeeService myService;

@Override
public void run(String...args) throws Exception {
    myService.getYearlyFeeForMember(1,1);

}
}
```

A service to make the repository calls:

```
@Service
public class FeeService {
public Double yearlyFee;

public List<TBeitragstabelle> fees = new ArrayList<>();
public List<TMitglieder> members = new ArrayList<>();

@Autowired
private MemberRepository memberRepository;



public Double getYearlyFeeForMember(int memberID, long year) {

    this.members= memberRepository.findAll(); //returns empty list
    Optional<TMitglieder> mitglieder = memberRepository.findById(Integer.toUnsignedLong(1)); // does not find anything

    System.out.println("members: ");

    for (TMitglieder member : members) {
        System.out.println("--->" + member.getName());
    }


    return yearlyFee;
}
}
```

**Why am I getting an empty list??**

However this is working fine --> used by my WebApplication. I just Call /members and all the members are found:

Controller:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class MitgliederController {
private List<TMitglieder> memberList;

@Autowired
private MemberRepository memberRepository;

@GetMapping("/members")
public List<TMitglieder> getAllMember() {
    memberList = memberRepository.findAll();
    return memberList;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try adding basePackages to enable jpa repo annotation and entity scan annotation.
eg:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.examples.jpa.repositories")

@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.examples.entity")
```

Also add @EnableAutoConfiguration will scan the given package(s) for detecting the entities.